# I can't upgrade my S III software from 4.0.4 to 4.1.1

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Samsung have released the 4.1.1 update for the SGS III and I am trying to upgrade my software from 4.0.4 to 4.1.1, but my Galaxy S III keeps saying:

> The server is busy or not available now, try another time or use the
>   PC Kies to upgrade it.
>   When I used the PC kies it gave me the message shown in thi pic below :
>   [image]

Is there any way to solve this problem? I'm very eager to upgrade my phone Jelly Bean.

Comment: Have you tried using PC Kies to upgrade it?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to use PC Kies to upgrade it ? can you explain it to me , kindly ??

Comment: What carrier are you on? Here are the instructions for the ATT SIII in the US: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/SupportOwnersFAQPopup.do?faq_id=FAQ00050358&fm_seq=55362

Comment: you may want to have a better data or wifi connection.

Comment: As suggested by Compro01 in the Answers you could try using ODIN to upgrade your device. Instructions for the GT-I9300 (Which it appears you have) can be found here: http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-s3-i9300-android-4-1-1-jelly-bean-official-upgrade-118073/

Comment: does ODIN loosen my warranty ?? does ODIN mean that my S III will be rooted ?

Comment: BTW when I use the PC kies to download the upgrade it reaches 14% or 45 % or 80 % and stops suddenly , is that something happens regularly ?

Comment: @Yahya Ahmed No to both warranty loss and root if you're flashing an official Samsung-signed image, like the ones samfirmware provide.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you've got 2 options

1. Use Kies to install the upgrade.
2. Wait until your carrier's wind-up toy servers get un-overloaded.

A third option would be to obtain an image of the appropriate firmware (e.g. from [samfirmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/)) and flash it via ODIN, though this is slightly more involved.

As an addendum, I was getting this myself with my own GS3 on Virgin mobile Canada (aka Bell Canada) and I ended up waiting just about 2 days, from the initial reports of people upgrading on Sunday until I got it late Tuesday evening.